# AssertionError: Sizes of $152.6, $152.48 do not match being thrown in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, assertion

I am using python to write a program. In my method, I return a tuple a,b,c, and in another place, I try to say x,y,z = self.some_method(), but then I get an assertion error that states: AssertionError: Sizes of $152.6, $152.48 do not match.

I honestly have no idea why this is happening, and I don't even know what $152.6 and $152.48 is. The line it is throwing this error is definitely on the line where I try to do x,y,z = self.some_method(), so I am not sure what the problem is.

There is no error in the method itself, and google has been unhelpful for trying to figure out what the dollar signs are.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Please post the stack trace, as well as your code that the stack trace references.

Comment: If you have no idea how your code works or how it is organized or what it does, we sure won't know especially if you don't include a [mcve].